# Getting started with firefox add-ons... Is the SDK the way to go?

Tags: firefox-addon

What is the most current way to build a firefox extension? I realize this question as been asked many times before, but the answers I found no longer seem up to date enough, especially since the add-on builder has been ditched.

So far I have spent a bit of time learning XUL, the add-on builder, and the SDK. There are many tutorials out there for all and I have found it very frustrating to spend some time with each before realizing it is outdated. Even the SDK tutorials are often flagged "In need of technical review" or are a couple of years old.

If the SDK is the best way to get started, are the official Mozilla tutorials the most up to date? Are there other good alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the type of add-on you want to create and how much effort you're willing to put in...

- Simple add-ons, like add-ons creating some toolbar button and/or interacting with web pages or doing some XHR to display some info: The SDK is likely best suited for your needs.
- Everything that could be a Greasemonkey user script: SDK and `page-mod`.
- Add-ons that are aimed at modifying/augmenting/enhancing Firefox (UI) itself are very likely better off going the XUL (overlay) road.
- Very complex add-ons, that will e.g. will use some own dialogs/windows are likely better off using XUL (overlays) as well. Also it is kinda possible to use "websites" / html instead of real windows and dialogs (but usually the results suck IMHO).
- If you're really into pain, bootstrapped (plain restartless add-ons without the SDK) are always another option.

You should keep in mind that the supported API of the SDK is still pretty limited and hides tons of low-level stuff by design. Therefore, right now, lots of SDK add-ons will use the `chrome` module anyway, and leave the safe surroundings of the SDK doing so...

I personally do not like the SDK, because I find it to be too limiting, and once you stumble upon a bug in the SDK itself (or at least think you found one), actually reading the vast abstractions that is the SDK is rather painful.
But then again the learning curve for simple stuff is rather tiny, so for beginners trying to create simple add-ons, it is a good fit.

Comment: Hahaha really into pain?? That's who bootstrap is for?? I love bootstrap!!! :P It's not about the pain its just the simplicity and you got control over everything!! :P You should make DownThemAll bootstrap :P It's restartless fun!

Comment: @Noitidart, I already did make DownThemAll! bootstrap quite some time ago (and currently trying to get e10s to work correctly), see our Nightlies.

Comment: Oh awesome! Loving dTa, some guy had an awesome idea in the feedback section to apply the 4x download speed to youtube streaming and other streaming videos, maybe your team can make a second addon out of that, it would be a super hit!! :)